# CloudFormation::Init yum install package from file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm setting up an EC2 instance with Cloudformation and configuring it using helper scripts.  I have a local .rpm that needs installed.  Typically this would be done with 'yum install myfile.rpm -y'.  Is there a way to do this using AWS::CouldFormation::Init packages?  I haven't seen anyway to specify a local file.

```
  'AWS::CloudFormation::Init':
    configSets:
      Install:
        - install
    install:
      packages:
        yum:
          #somehow specify local package
```

Comment: Can you upload it somewhere accessible via http? `yum` will accept http urls.

Comment: I don't see how to pass a url, the only parameter I can find is a version.  If I had to go through the trouble of uploading the file just to install it, it would be easier to forget about using packages, and instead just call the yum command in the commands section.